# How can I add a Note to an answer that stopped working with an Windows update?

Tags: support

I would like to add the following

**NOTE: This doesn't seem to work after Windows 10 feature update 2004!**

to save people's time for reading an answer https://superuser.com/a/1242730/549571 that stopped working.

How can I do this if

> Mokubai♦ reviewed this 2 days ago: Reject
> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reject reason states "It should have been written as a comment or an answer." If you have a solution then post an answer, if not then post a comment saying what is wrong.

Additionally the answer itself also states "I cannot guarantee this will work for everyone" which is disclaimer enough. It may be that the answer already didn't work for many people and adding a list of situations that didn't work could make for an answer with a lot of "works"/"didnt work" preamble that is just noise at the beginning of an answer.

Apparently you have already posted a comment. In this case that is all you should really do.

Comment: "The reject reason" is not a reason but a plain statement. I have given reasons why it needs to be in the answer. Therefore please except my edit. The "disclaimer" is not obvious and not enough. As other people and I have confirmed it used to work until Windows update 2004.

Comment: The disclaimer *is* obvious. "It may not work for you", YMMV, IANAL, however you want to state it it clearly implies it may stop working at any time for any number of reasons including updates. Adding a list of things it *won't* work on to the top of the answer is noise as you would quickly end up with a whole page of "doesn't work on Lenovo xR5" or "works on Dell FlibbleWidget6" and is just useless. All advice is subject to the whims of software and hardware designers and what may work now may stop in 5 minutes.

Comment: You've left a comment and as far as I'm concerned that is enough unless you can state *why* it no longer works with an explanation, in which case that may warrant a new question rather than digging up an old answer just to say "Nope." You could even post a bounty asking for new answers that *do* work with 2004. There are many better ways to do it than defacing old answers.

Comment: @FrankBreitling As a final point, are you proposing that you go through ***every*** answer on our site and editing in their version applicability or the exact date they stopped working? If so then I commend your dedication. If not, then why does this one particular answer deserve to be singled out?

Comment: The only thing I am proposing is to save the reader time by adding a "Note" at the beginning since a comment only appears at the end. The "Note" is important since it addresses a problem from a new Windows update which the author could not address at the time of posting his answer. Therefore I assume the author and readers would appreciate my edit.